# How to stream a motion jpeg using owin/katana?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, owin, katana

I am self hosting OWIN/KATANA in a windows service.  Right now I have implemented a way to grab a single image from a camera.  I would like to grab multiple frames from the camera and stream them back to a img tag on an html page.  Is this possible with OWIN/KATANA?

Comment: Are you asking "Given a series of still frames, how do I convert that into a video?" or "Given a video, how do i stream that using OWIN/KATANA?"

Comment: I will be taking a series of still frames that I would like to stream back to the client live.  I have a connection to the camera and can probably snap 30 frames per second.  Is it possible to stream that back with OWIN/KATANA?

Comment: You specifically mentioned the <video> tag: The <video> tag needs a video stream such as a .MP4.  Can you get that from the camera?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/n3wtron/4624820.  This is what I want to be able todo.  I just noticed it uses the img tag so that is what I would use.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  That isn't using a video tag though.  It looks to be sending a series of JPEG files.  Kinda like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.Map("/Camera/Video", a =>
{
    a.Run(context =>
    {
        string connectionid = CurrentDevice.Value.ToString();
        object ret = DeviceManager.Instance.SendMessageToDevice(connectionid, "startmovie");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", new string[] { "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary" });

        bool con = true;
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Body);
        while (con)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Image img = (Image)DeviceManager.Instance.SendMessageToDevice(connectionid, "capturestill");
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] buffer = ms.GetBuffer();

                writer.WriteLine("--jpgboundary");
                writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Content-length: {0}", buffer.Length));
                writer.WriteLine();
                context.Response.Write(buffer);
                //writer.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
                writer.Flush();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        DeviceManager.Instance.SendMessageToDevice(connectionid, "stopmovie");
        return context.Response.WriteAsync("");
    });
});
```

I figured out what my issue was.  I was using WriteAsync and I needed to use just the Write.  The above works great. I just need to figure out how to stop it now.